# Google Assistant/Dialogflow/Actions: how to get user's contacts?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

How do i get contacts of a user, who uses my Dialogflow?

One can pronounce phone, but this type of contact is not suitable for sending rich messages (somewhat large text and files). Also, phone considered to be too sensitive information by many people

And it's next to impossible to pronounce email properly, google will recognise it like bunch of random words instead.

So, what are my options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per Actions on Google policy, you should gain explicit access from a user to obtain their email address. You can do so by Account Linking in the Actions on Google project console:

1. Under "Account Linking" in the Actions on Google console, click on "Yes, allow users to sign up for new accounts via voice" and choose "Google Sign In" in the Linking Type field.
2. In your webhook ask user to sign in with `conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'))`.
3. Then, create a Dialogflow intent with the `actions_intent_SIGN_IN` event and allow fulfillment.

Then, in the fulfillment for the intent created in the last step, you will have access to user's email:

```
app.intent('Get Signin', (conv, params, signin) => {
  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    const email = conv.user.email
    conv.ask(`I got your email as ${email}. What do you want to do next?`)
  } else {
    conv.ask(`I won't be able to save your data, but what do you want to next?`)
  }
})
```

Reference -

- [Actions on Google client library doc](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation.user.html#email)
- [Actions on Google policies](https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies)

Comment: I also have this doubt. But I see this question as wanting to be able to train dialogflow with each user's contacts' list, so when the user wants, for instance, to send a message to a person that exists in his contacts list, chances are high that the name will be easily well interpreted. Only using sys_name, that recognizes common names, might not be sufficient to satisfy a user that uses its own contacts list names a lot. That's how I see this question.